# Can I be penalized for using breadcrumbs and subcategories for similar content?

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content, breadcrumbs

I am building a new navigation system via breadcrumbs based on categories and sub-categories.

Example 1:

```
Having url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale-red-vauxhall

Having breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback > Vauxhall > Red
```

That Page has 10 red cars.

Example 2:

```
Having another url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale-vauxhall

Having another breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback > Vauxhall
```

That Page has same 10 cars but users may add in the future cars which are not red.

Example 3:

```
Having another url like this:
http://mywebsite.com/listings-in-london-hatchback-car-for-sale

Having another breadcrumbs like this:
Home Page > Listings > London > For Sale > Car > Hatchback
```

That Page has too same 10 cars but users may add in the future cars which are not vauxhall.

There can be similar situations for other categories. Is it bad practice ? Can it be the cause for duplicate content penalty ? What should i do for avoid any penalties ?

Comment: Was it irrelevant question regarding to answers, which aren't exists ?

Answer (score 1):

It's only a duplicate content penalty if two URLs pull up the same content or very similar content (e.g. the same content but the content is slightly rearranged/sorted differently). Your example doesn't meet this criteria so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

That´s not a SEO problem at all, don´t worry